# How to display data of an inner array & update values in Angular app?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I am trying to create an Angular app that tracks my gym workouts.

The below array contains the various exercise names, reps, sets, weight, etc. within that workout:

```
workoutExercises = [
    {
      id: 0,
      name: "Close Grip Bench ",
      setOne: [5, 18.5, false], // repitition, weight, setComplete
      setTwo: [3, 18.5, false],
      setThree: [2, 18.5, false],
      setFour: [8, 18.5, false],
      setFive: [8, 18.5, false],
      currentExercise: true,
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Barbell Rows",
      setOne: [5, 19, false],
      setTwo: [3, 28.5, false],
      setThree: [2, 38, false],
      setFour: [8, 47.5, false],
      setFive: [8, 47.5, false],
      currentExercise: false,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Pull Ups",
      setOne: [6, 0, false],
      setTwo: [6, 0, false],
      currentExercise: false,
    },
  ];
```

On the UI, I want info from the first set `setOne: [5, 18.5, false]` to display.

Then when the user clicks `Done`, I want to move onto the next set `setTwo: [3, 18.5, false]`, & display that info, & so on.

I was thinking of putting in something like a `currentExercise` boolean on the first set, & update it when the set is complete, but I'm sure there's a better way.

Could someone please tell me what the best approach with be to this issue?

*Note: When one entire exercise is complete then, I want to move onto the first set of the next exercise.*

Comment: This data format probably isn’t ideal for what you need. Because you use objects, you’ll need to kinda hardcode the ‘next set’ in order to display or use it. Probably better to have you sets as an array of arrays or an array of objects. Something like {id: 1, sets:[{reps: 5, weight: 8, done: true},{reps: 10, weight:5, done: false}]}. That way it would be easier to move to the next set simply by increasing index.

Comment: Thanks @MikeOne. I had a feeling there was an issue with the structure I was trying to use. I'll try & implement your suggestion above & update the question accordingly.

Comment: @MikeOne Would I have an array of objects like the one you mentioned in your comment?

Answer (score 0):

One this you can do to improve your data model is to group your exercise step in an array called steps:

```
const workoutExercises = [
  {
    id: 0,
    name: "Close Grip Bench ",
    sets: [
      [5, 18.5], // repitition, weight, setComplete
      [3, 18.5],
      [2, 18.5],
      [8, 18.5],
      [8, 18.5]
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Barbell Rows",
    sets: [
      [5, 19],
      [3, 28.5],
      [2, 38],
      [8, 47.5],
      [8, 47.5]
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Pull Ups",
    sets: [
      [6, 0],
      [6, 0]
    ]
  }
];
```

after that you can transform your object to have a single array with several objects, each one is gonna contain one set alone with its id and name:

```
const workouts = workoutExercises.map(e => [...e.sets.map(val => {
  return {name: e.name, id: e.id, set: val}
}
)]).flat()
console.log(workouts)
```

result in console:
[image]
link to stackblitz example: [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-auyceb?file=index.ts)